# Is there a way to improve performance in a React 18 application when navigating away from a page with many components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I recently updated from React 16 to React 18 and performance during rendering has decreased substantially. The issue appears to be that unmounting components is a slow process. I ran a performance analysis navigating away from the same page and I can see that when I am using React 18 the event handler on page transition takes almost 3 seconds versus 750ms for the same thing in React 16. I am also seeing this lagging behavior any time a component with many children (like a table) is removed from the DOM. Running the React Profiler shows "react commit" is taking up most of the time. Is there some way to make improve React 18 performance when removing components from the screen? Has anyone else noticed this behavior?

I included screenshots of the performance analysis from clicking on a link to navigate away from a page with a table.

[image: React 18 performance]

[image: React 16 Performance]

Comment: Any new on this ? I have a same problem, but also i think when coming to the page with many components... I don't have profiling pictures but differences between react 18 and 17 are also very noticable..

Comment: It turns out that, react 18 have bad performance only in dev. I am not sure why is that, but after testing application in prod mode, everything seems to work fine...

Comment: It turns out that, react 18 have bad performance because of many warning checks and logs that happens only in dev

Comment: @Wings can you link some sources for that statement? Like what warnings and logs should we be looking out for?

Comment: Have you tried benchmark after a build? I had some performance issues while in dev mode. After I run a build everything goes smooth.